# How to make a desktop icons smaller in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, icons, desktop-icons

Just to clarify, I am  not trying to change the size of the launcher icons but the icons on the desktop. I realize there is bunch of posts related to smaller desktop icons but the suggested solutions didn't work for the version that I am currently using.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you the same guy in #ubuntu irc that told he wanted to make icons smaller, but actually the real issue he was having was graphic driver issues and then left?

Comment: nope, that wasn't me. I can resize the desktop icons individually but I would like to reduce the default icon size.